# Testing HttpRequest in a monadic way in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads

Suppose I would to test HTTP responses in Scala to make sure my web application returns them as required.

For example, one response is required to have "status code" = Ok, "content-type: application/json" and "content-length" headers and a valid JSON body, another one is required to have "status code" = Bad Request and an error message, etc.

Suppose I have defined a few functions to test status, header, and body

```
 def testStatus(status:Status): HttpResponse => Either[String, Status] = ...
 def doesHeaderExist(name: String): HttpResponse => Either[String, Header] = ...
 def testBody(body: Body): HttpResponse => Either[String, Body] = ...

 ... // etc.
```

Now I need to *compose* them to define a function to test a response.

I would like to do it in a *monadic* way, i.e. define a *monad*`ResponseTest[A]`

```
case class ResponseTest[A](req: HttpResponse, ea: Either[String, A]) {
  def unit(resp: HttpResponse, a: A) = ...
  def flatMap(f: A => ResponseTest[B]): ResponseTest[B] = ... 
}
```

re-define the test functions to return `ResponseTest` and compose them with the `flatMap` to  define functions to test entire response

```
  val testErrorResponse: HttpResponse => ResponseTest[HttpResponse] = ...
  val testJsonResponse: HttpResponse => ResponseTest[HttpResponse] = ...
```

Does it make sense ? How would you suggest implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make the actions something like this:

```
def doesHeaderExist(name: String): HttpResponse => Try[HttpResponse]
def testBoxy(contents: String): HttpResponse => Try[HttpResponse]
```

`Try` composes, so if it fails, then what you wind up with is either something that has your final type in a `Success` or the exception (and failing test) in a `Failure`.

```
val result = for{
 _1 <- doesHeaderExist("foo")(response)
 _2 <- testBody("bar")(_1)
} yield _2

result match{
  case Success(that) => //do stuff
  case Failure(ex) => //do stuff with the exception
}
```

And you handle the exception where it happened.

Comment: Maybe you are right and I do not need any `ResponseTest` class. Just one question: why `Try` rather than `Either` ?

Comment: @Michael Either does not compose. `Try` does. An even better way would be to wrap the functions themselves in `Try`. Hence, to start you'd make the first entrance `A => Success [ A]` and then compose thusly.

Comment: I do not understand how `Either` does not compose. It does not have `flatMap` but the _projections_ `Left` and `Right` do.